# JMeter v. 4 NTLM Authentication

Tags: apache, http, jmeter, ntlm-authentication, jmeter-4.0

I have an issue with NTLM Authentication, I'm using JMeter v. 4 and this is first time I'm using JMeter, so I'm beginner.

I've tried to follow couple of solutions that I found here but I'm still facing issue.

**HTTP Authorization Manager** has following values:

Base URL: http:// [test site]
Username: [my user name] - (have even tested with user@domain)
Password: [my password]
Domain: Domain
Realm: Empty - (have even tested with domain.local)
Mechanism: BASIC_DIGEST - (have even tested with KERBEROS)

My **HTTP Request** has following:
**Basic**
Server Name or IP: http:// [test site]
Method: GET
Use KeepAlive is enabled
Browser.compatible headers is enabled
**Advanced**
Implementation: HttpClient4

I have tried to edit \bin\user.properties\ and added **Setting** *httpclient4.auth.preemptive=true* or *httpclient4.auth.preemptive$Boolean=true* but still having issue:

Response message: Unauthorized

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
Date: Fri, 02 Mar 2018 08:42:30 GMT
Content-Length: 1293

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html
DataEncoding: iso-8859-1

The configurations that I have are based on [JMeter NTLM authentication failing 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917662/jmeter-ntlm-authentication-failing). Is there any difference between versions? What am I missing? What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. According to [HTTP Specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.47) there could be multiple [WWW-Authenticate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) headers in the server response.
2. According to [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-4.6) the client must choose the strongest option, in your case it is `Negotiate` which most probably means [Kerberos](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/) so I would suggest trying out configuring JMeter for Kerberos.

Check out [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for more information on configuring JMeter to deal with advanced authentication challenges.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Negotiate means that the server can use NTLM or Kerberos and as I earlier wrote, I have tested with both options.